# GeoServer JDBC connect error

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, jdbc

I installed a clean version of the GeoServer 2.20.4 on Windows, I create "User Group Services" JDBC to connect to the PostgreSQL database and add a user, create "Authentication Providers" and add it to the "Provider Chain".
But if I try to log in as a user from the database, I get an error. The user is added to the database.

> 23 May 10:31:33 WARN [wicket.Localizer] - Tried to retrieve a localized string for a component that has not yet been added to the page. This can sometimes lead to an invalid or no localized resource returned. Make sure you are not calling Component#getString() inside your Component's constructor. Offending component: [JDBCUserGroupServicePanel [Component id = dummy]]
> 23 May10:33:32 WARN [geoserver.security] - JDBC connect error
> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: JDBC connect error
> at org.geoserver.security.jdbc.JDBCConnectAuthProvider.authenticate(JDBCConnectAuthProvider.java:87)
> at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(GeoServerAuthenticationProvider.java:54)
> at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175)
> at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityManager$1.authenticate(GeoServerSecurityManager.java:314)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
> at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
> at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:102)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:201)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:602)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:191)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:146)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:273)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
> at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ?????: ???????????? "aaa" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:646)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180)
> at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
> at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
> at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:223)
> at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400)
> at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
> at org.geoserver.security.jdbc.JDBCConnectAuthProvider.authenticate(JDBCConnectAuthProvider.java:82)
> ... 74 more
> 23 May 10:33:32 WARN [geoserver.security] - Failed login, user aaa from [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
> 23 May 10:33:32 INFO [geoserver.security] - Brute force attack prevention, delaying login for 4606ms

Comment: there's a postgres error in connecting - can you connect from the command line using psql?

Comment: no error, connect